# .parent().toggleClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggleclass

I have a fiddle right here: https://jsfiddle.net/qxnk05ua/2/

When I click the button, I want the background to change color, very simple. Why does it not work?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: missing jQuery library

Comment: My Magento setup has the jQuery loaded in, work perfectly with all the other functions. The fiddle might miss the jQuery, but that is not where the problem is located

Comment: Just added jquery to your fiddle and it working fine https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/3817/

Comment: It's working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/qxnk05ua/4/

Comment: I am sorry, it seems I made a spelling mistake :/ Thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add jquery library in your HTML

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js

Answer (score 1):

You missed the jQuery reference. Add below reference to your code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is an working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qxnk05ua/7/)

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer. Next time check your console, before posting.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.block{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#FFF;
}
.block.active{
  background-color:#333;
}

.block button{
  padding:5px;
  color:#333;
  width:100px;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 50px);
  margin-top:calc(50% - 20px);
  border:none;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#FAC657;
  border-bottom:3px solid #CFA54A;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.block button:active{
  margin-top:calc(50% - 17px);
  border-bottom:none;
  outline:none;
  box-shadow:none;
  -moz-box-shadow:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow:none;
}
.block button:focus{
  outline:none;
  box-shadow:none;
  -moz-box-shadow:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <button>
    change color
  </button>
</div>
```